# Remote queue consumer misses first message after restart

Tags: python, python-3.x, queue, multiprocessing

I have code like the following:

#### server.py

```
import queue
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

q = queue.Queue()
QueueManager.register('queue', callable=lambda:q)
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 51000), authkey=b'pass')
s = m.get_server()
s.serve_forever()
```

#### producer.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager
import time

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

QueueManager.register('queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 51000), authkey=b'pass')
m.connect()
queue = m.queue()

idx = 0
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    queue.put(idx)
    idx += 1
```

#### consumer.py

```
from multiprocessing.managers import BaseManager

class QueueManager(BaseManager):
    pass

QueueManager.register('queue')
m = QueueManager(address=('localhost', 51000), authkey=b'pass')
m.connect()
queue = m.queue()

while True:
    message = queue.get()
    print(message)
```

If I run the server and the producer and then start the consumer I see all messages that the producer put in the queue appear at the consumer. However, if I stop the consumer and immediately restart it it always skips a message.

To illustrate what I see as output of the consumer.py:

```
0
1
2
3
<restart the consumer>
5
6
7
etc.
```

Is this just how the python multiprocessing queue is supposed to work, is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: How you restart the consumer?

Comment: I just kill it with Ctrl+C and start it again

Comment: You are killing the consumer while the producer is putting the integers to queue so how do you expect it prints the previous item?

Comment: It also happens if I kill the consumer before the producer puts the next integer in the queue. I would expect this integer to just remain in the queue until there is a consumer to consume it, however it seems as if killing the consumer affects the queue.

Comment: @Semi: I played about 1 more hour with your code and couldn't get it to work, see my updated answer below, I would file this as a bug

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue lies in either the way pipes are implemented in python, or it might even be a limitation on the OS. Here's the full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "consumer.py", line 12, in <module>
    message = queue.get()
  File "<string>", line 2, in get
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/managers.py", line 757, in _callmethod
    kind, result = conn.recv()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 250, in recv
    buf = self._recv_bytes()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 407, in _recv_bytes
    buf = self._recv(4)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.0/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 379, in _recv
    chunk = read(handle, remaining)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

The value seems to be lost in the `queue.get()` call which is not properly terminated with the `SIGINT`. The `queue.get()` gets instantly cancelled, so it's not that python would finish the `get()` call and then lose the value. It looks more like python does not properly cancel the `recv` on the pipe.

If you are changing the consumer to this:

```
while True:
    while queue.empty():
        sleep(0.1)
    message = queue.get()
    print(message)
```

it will work. But of course it's a workaround and not the real solution.

**Update:**

After playing around more with your code I think this is a bug, since:

1. you [followed their coding example one by one](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-remote-manager)
2. no type of queue solves the problem (neither `multiprocessing.Queue` nor `multiprocessing.JoinableQueue`
3. also sending `task_done()` is not helping

The bug is happening both on python2 and python3. I suggest you [report this as a bug](https://bugs.python.org/). In the worst case, if it is not a bug, you at least get an explanation why python would behave this way.

Comment: Thanks for putting your time into this, I have tried several things too, but without success. For now I reported it as a bug: http://bugs.python.org/issue29454